# blogger main page strange white space code

Tags: css, blogger

On the main page of my blog: http://www.laboiteaprog.com, there is a problem like you can see with the archive menu at the right.

I checked the html web page and there are this code

```
<style type="text/css">
p, li {
    white-space: pre-wrap;
}
</style>
```

a couple of times.

It seems the problem happens only on the home page.

Like we can see on this one and other pages, the problem is not happening.
http://www.laboiteaprog.com/2011/08/language-implementation-patterns.html

when i click on the template and modify html code, i don't see

```
white-space: pre-wrap;
```

so i don't know how to remove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you absolutely can't find that bit in your templates, you could, as a temporary solution, override it, in your css:

```
    body p,
    body li {
        white-space: normal;
    }
```

Comment: strange, can't find it, surely something generate it.  i override the css with you code and that work fine.

Comment: it could be a plugin that does that, check if you have any plugins that are active on the homepage only